# how to write first class honors in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have finally graduated with a first class honors in bachelor degree in Software Engineering.

is this sentence correct? it seems wrong

Comment: It'd be entirely wrong if I said it. What do you think is wrong with it? In what context are you using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few thing wrong with how this sentence is phrased.

Having finally before 'graduated' would imply that one had trouble competing the following action which I don't think is the intend of the statement here.

A correct usage of finally would be the following.

*After playing for several hours, I finally completed the game.*

Secondly you need not add 'a' after with in this case.

**Graduated with first class honours** is the right usage.

The last part is tricky

Whatever is the course name that was graduated in should be perfectly fine to add after the snippet *Graduated with first class honours*.

But having a 'in' in the course name makes it sound odd.

**I graduated with first-class honours in software engineering**

Is the right usage and conveys the general intend.

Additionally one could say

**I graduated with first-class honours for my bachelors in software engineering**